# FB.api('/me/accounts',...) got broken April 30th 2015

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After April 30th 2015, when Graph API v1.0 Deprecation performed, the code below has not given accounts any more, though it worked earlier:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', {}, function(response) {...} );
```

However you get the accounts if you copy accessToken from Graph API Explorer and paste to code below:

```
var access_token = 'CAACEd...';
FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', 
{"access_token":access_token}, function(response) {...} );
```

AccessToken should though get programmable. Below is the right way for getting it, but it gives different (wrong) accessToken value than Graph API Explorer. Why?

```
var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
```

Comment: Does your access token include `manage_pages` permission? (Go check via the FB debug tool, if unsure.) Also, if you want to ask users that don’t have a role in the app to ask for that permission, you have to get it approved in review before you can do so.

Comment: Now it works, manage_pages was missing in my access token. Thank you!